# Sum query result by name specified by regex

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am using Grafana together with Prometheus to display data of my Pods from Kubernetes Cluster. Here I am displaying Memory Usage for each Pod by name:

```
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="namespace1", image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) by (pod_name)
```

It gives correct result for each pod. In example:

```
    namespace1-eventstore-1
    namespace1-eventstore-0
    avsandbox-X-64ff4d-rl9z6
    avsandbox-X-64ff4d-ldfnx
    avsandbox-Y-7d9df9ddff-asdf
    avsandbox-Y-7d9df9ddff-dfas
    avsandbox-Z-5957dbaf58dt-gds24
    avsandbox-Z-5957dbaf58dt-g4gd7
```

Now I want to sum them by their respective names to receive following result or closest I can get to it

```
    namespace1-eventstore
    avsandbox-X
    avsandbox-Y
    avsandbox-Z
```

So in conclusion I want to sum everything that has same name before second `-`. How can I achieve that?

Edit.: Here's further example what I'm looking for (hopefully it's helpful to give practical example and general idea)

```
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="namespace1", image!="",name=~"^k8s_.*",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) by (pod_name="([a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9])-.*")
```

But that's not possible because of syntax.